# Where's 'AllowDrop' in the VS PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, drag-and-drop, propertygrid

I can't find `AllowDrop` property on `RichTextBox` control (sorted alphabetically):

[image]

I'm sure that there's this property because it compile fine (and make working the RichTextBox's Drag-and-drop)

```
msg_textBox.AllowDrop = true;
```

I don't understand because the VS didn't show it.

Comment: Some things dont expose it there but you can set it to true in code.  Not sure about RTB, but thats the case for a PicBox.  In the case of the PB it was reported as a bug long ago and the response was that it was by design.

Comment: Neither the Drag* events are listed too. I'm curious to know what by design really mean

Comment: You can add the events too, just manually (at least for PicBox)

Comment: Yeah, I did it. But I'm still curious why it isn't displayed on the VS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [.NET Framework Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBox.cs,58632b11220710a1) is an excellent way to find the answer to questions like this.  Quoting the comment on the RichTextBox.AllowDrop property (edited to fit):

> ///     RichTextBox controls have built-in drag and drop support, but
>   ///     AllowDrop, DragEnter, DragDrop may still be used:
>   ///     this should be hidden in the property grid, but not in code

What that "built-in drag and drop support" actually looks like is a bit mysterious btw.  Fairly sure it was meant to allow dragging of embedded OLE objects.  RichTextBox is one of the last remaining pieces of Microsoft software that still supports OLE.  It is otherwise dead as a doornail and I have no programs still installed anymore that have it, that I know of anyway.

So, laser to stun and follow the guidance from the comment, simply set AllowDrop to *true* in the form constructor.

Comment: Such a great reference. :) I'm not used yet to look at directly Microsoft's source code implementation... thanks